# Can Partner Community users edit their email preferences?

Tags: community, email, administration, user, setup

Standard Salesforce users can got to **Setup > My Email Setting** (or https://cs14.salesforce.com/p/email/UserEmailPrefEdit) to get this page:

[image]

is a comparable setting also available for Partner Community users? The are not allowed to visit the URL mentioned above. Also I did not find any other place to tweak it?

At My **Settings > Email Settings** a got some stuff but no place where I can change the **Email Name** and **Signature**. Is that missing for Partner Users?

[image]

Extra question: for Standard Users where in the database (on which object) these settings will be saved? What are their API names? I was not able to locate the Email Name and Signature on the user record. Should I look anywhere else?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Salesforce Communities Implementation guide](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/200/8/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_communities_implementation.pdf#networks_contact_info_visibility), users can edit their email preferences in:

> Your Name > Edit Contact Info, then click Contact

Reason you can't see the option to set these prefs might be that the field is restricted from viewing through the API.